# How to depend another project's androidTestCompile?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-project test issue: I want one project to depend on another project's `androidTestCompile`.
I have tried this way:

```
 androidTestCompile project(':CommonTest').sourceSets.androidTest
```

But android studio says it could not find property androidTest on SourceSet container.

Help

Comment: What's the name of the other project, & which folder is it in relative to this project?

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-project-setup explains multi-projects. They discuss how to run all the tests. Quote: "Then from the root folder, the following command line will run all the tests and aggregate the reports:
`gradle deviceCheck mergeAndroidReports --continue`

Note: the `--continue` option ensure that all tests, from all sub-projects will be run even if one of them fails."   NB: this doesn't answer your question, but may help you discover what to do.

Comment: And https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html explains multi-projects in Gradle (independently of any Android foibles).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that *might* work. I've not tried it as I don't have a multi-project Android project. You'll need to tweak the code for your project names and specify the `dependsOn` in your current projects task for Android Tests.

```
task action(dependsOn: ":producer:action") << {
    println("Consuming message: ${rootProject.producerMessage}")
}
```

See the topic `24.6.1.2. Declaring dependencies` in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Another clue is in the Gradle Java Tutorial which explains how to establish dependencies between projects in a multi-project build https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#N14E23

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':shared')
}
```

So I'd hazard a guess that something like

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile project(':CommonTest')
}
```

(which you've tried, albeit with more parameters) is on the right track.